# JPA - ManyToOne & OneToMany strackoverflow exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a simple model with a **Employee** and **Company** objects.

The goal is to simply get a list of Employees with the companies they are working for, and a list of Companies and their employees.

The code belong is throwing exceptions caused by infinite recursive calls (stackloverflow). Since one relationships fetchs EARGLY and other LAZYLY, I can't understand the reason why it happens. It doesn't matter which data is being fetched (Company.findAll or Employee.findAll)

This is the database and entities configuration used in my project:

The relationships are:

```
ONE Company has MANY Employees.
MANY Employees have (work for) ONE Company
```

The owner side is Employee (it is the table that has a FK to Company) based on the idea that says: "there is no employee without a company, but the opposite can be true".

The way I understand the entity ownership is like that:
Employee owns the relationship, so, when we fecth **employee** data it also fetchs the **company** (ManyToOne) it belongs too, but when we fecth a **company** data, the **employees** (OneToMany) will not be fetched.

Employee entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
   private CompanyEntity company;
}
```

Company entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompanyEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private Set<EmployeeEntity> employees = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    company_id INT NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE Employee
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (company_id)
    REFERENCES company (id);
```

The ultimate goal would be to get it working in both ways.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to actually have the sample code that throws the exception. What I'm guessing is that since You have lombok @Data annotation there (which among other stuff generates also toString) that if You try to log some instances of those entities, it will lazily load the other referenced entity and then back the other one in an infinite loop.

So You can try removing the @Data annotation and see if it helps.

Comment: I know what you mean, but lombook is not the one causing that this time ... the stackkoverflow happens at fetching time, and not when I try to use (toString, equals or hashcode) the entity.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`.
The problem is that they are fetching each other. You get an `Employee` and with him, his `Company`, then the `Company` fetches its `Employees`, then its `Employees` their `Companies` and so on...

Check [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-managed-reference.html).

Change the Code this way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;


   @JsonManagedReference // <--------------
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
   private CompanyEntity company;
}
```

and

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompanyEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@JsonBackReference // <--------------
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private Set<EmployeeEntity> employees = new HashSet<>();
}
```

> `@JsonManagedReference` is the forward part of reference – the one
> that gets serialized normally. `@JsonBackReference` is the back part
> of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.

Comment: It worked. Could you explain how a Jackson annotation work at entity level? I mean, I'm not serializing those entities (at least not explicity). I would expect something from javax.persistence.* to solve it at this level.

Comment: When you fetch (GET) then you most likely return a JSON array with all your employees, or even when you get just one, the entity will be serialized right?
Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: as I said, I'm not serializing it explicity, if it happens behind the scenes somehow by JPA I would like to understand. I can se the exception (in debug mode) as soon as the entity returns from the @Repository class.

Comment: Do you mean right after you make a getAll function call?
Can you please add this part of code to your question?

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

The comment that lead me to this was @haki's comment.

The problem was being caused by a recursive call caused by equals/hashcode on the non-owner side of the relationship.

I would say **the rule of thumbs** on ManyToOne/OneToMany relationships is to either ignore equals/hashcode on the non-owner side class (in this case CompanyEntity field inside EmployeeEntity class) or implement them considering just one level deep.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
   @ToString.Exclude
   @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
   private CompanyEntity company;
}
```